# Android embedded Web-server with scripting capability

Tags: php, android, scripting, webserver, nanohttpd

I'd like to add an embedded web-server capability into my Android project. The server needs to server static files, **and** be scriptable (so I could implement my own server-client JSON-based APIs.)

Looking into [several similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20embedded%20webserver), the [NanoHTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) seems like a reasonable choice. However, there is lack of documentation regarding any scripting functionality.

For example, I'd like to POST a string to `http://device-ip/actions/do_something`, and the server should be able to invoke a function to process the request. (Alongside serving static files such as `/img/example.png` and `/assets/style.css`, obviously.)

If anyone in the past has worked with NanoHTTPD on any platform, could you provide an example to achieve this functionality?

---

However, if you can suggest other embedded servers, I'd be grateful if you could mention them in comments.

Comment: Yes. NanoHttp can receive POST requests. It's you who has to add code to handle the request. What you mean by scriptable is unclear.

Comment: Can you provide an example to handle POST requests and serve static files with GET requests as an answer please?

Comment: Examples come with NanoHttpd. And otherwise such examples have been posted here before. You should be able to find them with a little googling. It is the serve() method wich comes with all the parameters filled in with post or get. Then you only have to add code to handle the parameters.

Comment: Yes, @DRSDavidSoft. I made Android PC suite using NanoHttpd with to POST method. use can find here https://github.com/pathikdevani/Flysync/blob/master/flysync-android/flysync/src/main/java/com/pathik/server/NANOServer.java